# Yamaha DX7 Unit Generator Synth in java

Tags: java, class, audio, hierarchy, synthesis

I am a student studying Java this year. I have been set a task to code a class hierarchy to implement something like Yamaha DX7 Synthesiser in java. I am sorry if this is a beginner question. But I have combed the net for some tutorials or info in anyway and found nothing.

I would like to ask if anyone could recommend any sites or tutorials, or even perhaps examples of this type of code? I have found many C/supecolider based work in audio synthesis, but very little in Java

It would be based around the unit generator principal.(Ugens).

I am sorry to ask such a boring question i am just at a loss.

Thank you so much for your time.

P

Comment: Check out [JSyn](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/).

Comment: hey thanks a lot i had a look a this thats extremely helpful awesome

Answer (score 0):

checkout jfugue http://www.jfugue.org/

it is kinda popular library

"JFugue is an open-source Java API for programming music without the complexities of MIDI.

JFugue makes programming music this easy:

Player player = new Player();
player.play("C D E F G A B"); "

Comment: Again thanks for the suggestion. I had not seen this either. I am very new to Java coding and where I find I am having the greatest struggle is with the synthesis. Thanks o much going to have a look into this now. glad I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Also possibly of interest is [Bristol Audio Synthesis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bristol/) which is an open source software implementation of the various synths, including the DX series.

I suspect half of the battle with this problem is deriving a mathematical model of the synth such that you can express it as a network of unit generators.

Java is a almost never used for real-world software synthesis, so examples in Java will be thin on the ground.   The most common architecture you'll come across is as plugins such VST or AU - all of which are conceptually very similar, and usually implemented in C++.